# Cannot convert from SimpleIntegerProperty to Property<Integer>

Tags: java, function, javafx, lambda, properties

In the following code, `fStr` and `fInt` are nearly the same, except that one is String and one is Integer.

However, `fStr` doesn't have any error, and `fInt` has an error as: "Cannot convert from SimpleIntegerProperty to Property"

Why does that happen and how can I solve it? Thanks!

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Main{
      public static void main(String args[]){
    
            Function<myData, Property<String>> fStr;
            Function<myData, Property<Integer>> fInt;
        
            fStr = (myData e)-> {return e.getStr();};
            fInt = (myData e)-> {return e.getInt();};
        
         }

    public static class myData {
     
        private final SimpleStringProperty myStr = null;
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty myInt = null;

        public SimpleStringProperty getStr() {
            return myStr;
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty getInt() {
            return myInt;
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Based on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleIntegerProperty.html, it looks like `SimpleIntegerProperty` implements `Property<Number>` rather than `Property<Integer>`

Comment: fInt = (myData e)-> {return e.getInt().intValue();};

Comment: Thanks. `Property<Number>` solves the problem

Comment: There are `IntegerProperty::asObject` and `IntegerProperty::integerProperty​` depending on the direction of the conversion...